# Bootstrap tooltips not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm going mad here.

I've got the following HTML:

```html
<a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="A nice tooltip">test</a>
```

And the Bootstrap style tooltip refuses to display, just a normal tooltip.

I've got bootstrap.css working just fine, and I can see the classes in there

I've got all of the relevant JS files at the end of my HTML file:

```html
<script src="bootstrap/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
```

I've looked at the source of Bootstrap's example and cannot see anything that initiates the tooltip anywhere in there. So I'm guessing it should just work, or am I missing something vital here?

I've got modals and alerts and other things working just fine, so I'm not a total moron ;)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The tooltip is being initiated in the application.js file in twitters example. Can you post your html? Would like to take a look at how you're initializing the script.

Comment: Ahhhhh.... I ignored that given the first comment. So should this work: `code`<a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="A nice tooltip" class="tooltip-test">test</a><br>
                    <script>
                    // tooltip demo
         $('.tooltip-test').tooltip()
     </script>

Comment: don't forget to pass a selector to the tooltip options, `$('.tooltip-test').tooltip({ selector: "a" })`

Comment: Thanks Andres. Actually I didn't seem to need the selector in there, I think that's because the class of the a is referenced as tooltip-test.

Comment: Without the selector option the tooltip does not work for me, here is a demo i put up: http://jsfiddle.net/VXctp/, try it without the selector.

Comment: Has this been resolved? If not, then make sure that you are using the latest version of JQuery - I upgraded to [JQuery 1.7.2](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js) to make this work

Comment: If it's not working for you, make sure to include Popper BEFORE Bootstrap in your head.

Answer (score 293):

To sum up: activate your tooltips using jQuery selectors

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("[rel='tooltip']").tooltip();
    });
</script>
```

In fact, you don't need to use the attribute selector, you can invoke it on any element even if it doesn't have `rel="tooltip"` in its tag.

Comment: For those working with Rails, this is already defined in `bootstrap.js.coffee` with `$(".tooltip").tooltip()`. Just make sure to include `//= require bootstrap` in your `application.js`.

Comment: Adding the class .tooltip to any element will break the tooltips for me. The content inside the element with the class .tooltip will hide and the tooltip will show if I manage to found the hidden element in with my mouse.

Using any other selector or class name will work fine.\

Comment: @Leito that is correct, bootstrap defines styles for `.tooltip` and by default, they are invisible. You can use the `rel` attribute or any other class as a selector, though.

Comment: Yes, you need BOTH the HTML Markup and the JS Selectors. These are not alternative ways to apply tooltips.

Comment: Some might be trying to display a tooltip in a modal and this does not work in all bootstrap versions. If you try it in a normal page, not a modal, and it works, then you know that's the problem.

Comment: You can also run into problems trying to run tooltips from pages loaded with AJAX. Try it on a portion of the page that is not dynamically loaded with Ajax and see if it works then.

Comment: Thank you for this! If i initialize all at once, how can i define another direction for some tooltips? Can options be set even in the tag attribute?

Comment: Got it: I use $("[rel='tooltip-bottom']").tooltip({placement:'bottom'}); and the accoarding attribute value rel="tooltip-bottom" or easyer add the data-placement="bottom" tag.

Comment: @slhck could you be more specific please?  What version of Rails, or what gem, initializes Bootstrap tooltip behind the scenes?  I'm seeing it in Rails 3.2.17 using boostrap-sass-3.1.1.0 but I can't find any line of code that does that

Comment: @IsaacBetesh Honestly, I don't remember – this was 1.5 years ago. The code we were using at the time was this: https://github.com/maphub/maphub-portal

Comment: Thank you.  I think you were referring to a different gem than bootstrap-sass.  Maybe twitter-bootstrap-rails?  I think what I saw was Chrome's native tooltip feature, not any JS library.

Comment: I was confused by bootstrap docs; I thought you needed no javascript, just the data attribute.

Comment: Thanks @Manuel Your suggestion fixed the tooltip for me. I'm using `Rails 4.2` Before that, I had bootstrap required in `application.js` but it wasn't work. Also I found I need to have `rel="tooltip"` declared in my HTML otherwise that JS function wouldn't work.

Answer (score 265):

After experiencing the same problem, I found this solution worked without having to add additional tag attributes outside of the Bootstrap required attributes.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Title Here">Hyperlink Text</a>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").tooltip({ selector: '[data-toggle=tooltip]' });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. Somehow the other solutions on this page weren't working for me.

Comment: I'm with Roman.  This solution works with the bootswatch css variants as well.

Comment: This worked for me. Nothing else kicked it into life until I tried this. Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me too. Any idea why   $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({'placement': 'top'}); doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. Just make sure that you insert the code between <script> tags AFTER you load the JQuery library.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that - it depends where your component is placed. In my case when it was just in main container it worked like in bootstrap doc, but when I put him into bootstrap tree it stopped to work. This solution fixed my problem

Comment: This still works for 4.1.3, unlike the default `$('body').tooltip()` and the answer of Manuel Ebert.

Comment: the selector is missing the quotes around the operand

Comment: this working so well, turns out tooltip need selector property.. you can't just do `$('body').tooltip();` it needs the selector property

Comment: @ZeroCool i think it missed by the div element tree like robson comment

Answer (score 33):

You don't need all js files separately

Just use the following files if you are going to use all bootstrap functions:

```
-bootstrap.css
-bootstrap.js
```

both of them can be found in http://twitter.github.com
and finally
-Latest version of jquery.js

---

**For Glyphicons** you need the image

glyphicons-halfings.png and/or glyphicons-halfings-white.png(white coloured images)
which you need to upload inside /img/ folder of your website (or) store it where ever you want but change the folder directory inside the bootstrap.css

---

**For tooltip** you need the following script inside your
`<head> </head>` tag

```
  <script type='text/javascript'>
     $(document).ready(function () {
     if ($("[rel=tooltip]").length) {
     $("[rel=tooltip]").tooltip();
     }
   });
  </script>
```

That's it...

Answer (score 29):

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips-usage

Opt-in functionality
For performance reasons, the Tooltip and Popover data-apis are opt-in, meaning

> **you must initialize them yourself.**

One way to initialize all tooltips on a page would be to select them by their data-toggle attribute:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
</script>
```

putting this piece of code in your html  allows you to use the tooltips

Examples:

```
<!-- button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip on left">Tooltip on left</button>

<!-- a tag -->
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Some tooltip text!">Hover over me</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this opt-in concept! Never read it from any tutorials.

Comment: The solution to all of my jquery/bootstrap tooltip whoas

Comment: Provided link is missing : please look at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/tooltips/

Answer (score 24):

HTML

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Title Here">Hyperlink Text</a>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[data-toggle=tooltip]').tooltip();
});
```

This one is work for me.

Comment: This proposal worked perfectly for me as well. I liked it because it is simple and elegant. It lets you keep using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/) standards as if the plugin came initilized by default, like happens with Dropdown and Tab elements. I added the JS proposed by @Igor to a new file and [bundled it](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification) to the original bootstrap.js

Answer (score 20):

I know this is an old question, but since I had this problem with the new release of bootstrap and its not clear on the website, here is how you enable the tooltip.

give your element a class like "tooltip-test"

then activate this class in your javascript tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.tooltip-test').tooltip();
</script>

<a href="#" class="tooltip-test" title="" data-original-title="Tooltip">This link</a>
```

Comment: This was the only solution which worked for me. I'm using data-original-title="{{someAngularJSVar}}" to update the title and it is working flawlessly.

Answer (score 19):

If you do `$("[rel='tooltip']").tooltip();` as other answers have suggested then you will activate tooltips only on elements that are currently there in DOM. That means if you are going to change DOM and insert dynamic content later it won't work. Also this is much less efficient because it installs event handler for *individual* elements as opposed to using JQuery event delegation. So the best way I've found to activate Bootstrap tooltips is this one line of code that you can place in document ready and forget about it:

```
$(document.body).tooltip({ selector: "[title]" });
```

Note that I'm using `title` as selector instead of `rel=title` or `data-title`. This has an advantage that it can be applied to many other elements (the `rel` is *supposed* to be only for anchors) and also it works as "fallback" for old browsers.

Also note that you don't need `data-toggle="tooltip"` attribute if you are using above code.

Bootstrap tooltips are expensive because you need to handle mouse events on each of the elements. This is the reason why they haven't enabled it by default. So if you ever decide to comment out above line, your page would still work if you use title attribute.

If you are OK not to use title attribute then I would recommend using pure CSS solution such as Hint.css or check http://csstooltip.com which does not require any JavaScript code at all.

Comment: I'm struggling with this one because the dynamic generation goes several levels deep. The href value is dynamically generated content and the resulting div id is based on the item number that matches the href value. So if I've got a page of links of Item Type A, then I have a list of item a-1, item a-2, item a-3, each of those links is to the items individual page, but I want the tooltip content to display dynamic content on hover, so the user can get some idea of the item before clicking on the full link.

Comment: This was the most helpful. I had the tooltip set to bind to an icon, and the icon library had some sort of asynchronous loading so it could not bind. It was so strange because it would work when using a class selector but not ID. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You are life saviour

Answer (score 15):

This is the simplest way.
Just put this before `</body>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("[data-toggle=\"tooltip\"]").tooltip();
</script>
```

Check out the examples given in the [Bootstrap's documentation about tooltips](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips).

For example:

```
<a href="#"
   data-toggle="tooltip"
   data-placement="bottom"
   title="Tooltip text here">Link with tooltip</a>
```

Comment: please close the type attribute... editing just a single typo is a PITA :S

Answer (score 10):

Tooltip and popover are NOT only-css plugins like dropdown or progressbar. To use tooltips and popover, you MUST to activate them using jquery (read javascript).

So, lets say we want a popover to be shown on click of an html button.

```
<a href="#" role="button" 
     class="btn popovers-to-be-activated" 
     title="" data-content="And here's some amazing content." 
     data-original-title="A Title" "
>button</a>
```

Then you need to have following javascript code to activate popover:

```
$('.popovers-to-be-activated').popover();
```

Actually, above javascript code will activate popover on all the html elements which have class "popovers-to-be-activated".

Needless to say, put the above javascript inside DOM-ready callback to activate all popovers as soon as DOM is ready:

```
$(function() {
 // Handler for .ready() called.
 $('.popovers-to-be-activated').popover();
});
```

Answer (score 8):

// Update

- Mar 2023: Included Tooltip for Bootstrap v5.x and v4.x

### Bootstrap v5.x (Tested)

#### Step 1

Include the Bootstrap CSS

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

#### Step 2

Add the HTML

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="I'm a Working Tooltip">Hover me!</button>
```

#### Step 3

Include all the scripts. You also need to activate the tooltip. If you want to move the jquery you can move it to an external file `activate-tooltip.js`.

> Tooltips are opt-in for performance reasons, so **you must initialize them yourself.**

See the FAQ below to know the script order.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
// If you do not want to use jQuery you can use Pure JavaScript. See FAQ below
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
</script>
```

### Bootstrap v4.x (Tested)

#### Step 1

Include the v4 css

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

##### Step 2

Add the HTML. Note that the `data-toggle` is for `v4` and `data-bs-toggle` for `v5`

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="I'm a Working Tooltip">Hover me!</button>
```

##### Step 3

See **Step 3** in **Bootstrap V5.x**. The only change you need to make is to change the `data-toggle`.

---

### FAQ

**What happens if you do not include jQuery?**
jQuery is to enable the tooltip. If not included tooltip won't work as expected and you will also get the `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` error in your console.

[image]

Without jQuery

[image]

With jQuery

[image]

**I'm not seeing a small arrow in the tooltip.**
Make sure you use the correct Bootstrap CSS version

**What is the correct script order?**
You can use single script `bootstrap.bundle.js` or use two scripts `popper.min.js` and `bootstrap.min.js` with `jquery` and `activate-tooltip.js`

`activate-tooltip.js` is a one-line to activate the tooltip. See **Step 3**

> Tooltips rely on the 3rd party library Popper.js for positioning. You must include popper.min.js before bootstrap.js or use bootstrap.bundle.min.js / bootstrap.bundle.js which contains Popper.js in order for tooltips to work!

```js
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/activate-tooltip.js"></script>

// or

<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/activate-tooltip.js"></script>
```

**Can I use Vanilla JS instead of jQuery?**
Yes, use this code. From the [Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/tooltips/#example-enable-tooltips-everywhere)

```js
var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
    return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
});
```

Comment: Bootstrap 5 is designed to be used without jQuery, your step 2 is not the best solution.

Comment: if one intends to use jquery for other reasons and is available then why not use it? is it sin?

Comment: @probitaille I have updated the code. See my FAQ

Answer (score 5):

in head section you need to add the following code first

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
});
</script>
```

Then in the body section you need to do write the following code

```
<p>The data-placement attribute specifies the tooltip position.</p>
<ul class="list-inline">
<li><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Hooray!">Top</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Hooray!">Bottom</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Hooray!">Left</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Hooray!">Right</a></li>
```

Answer (score 4):

If everything is still not resolved Use Latest Jquery library, you dont need any of the jquery selectors if you use the latest bootstrap 2.0.4 and jquery-1.7.2.js

Just use `rel="tooltip" title="Your Title" data-placement=" "`

Use top / bottom / left / right in the data-placement as per your wish.

Answer (score 4):

Lets use an example to show how the Tooltips can be added to any HTML element in your document.

## NOTE:

If these tooltip samples don't work when you put them in your page, then you have another problem.  You need to look at things like:

- The order of scripts being included
- See if you are trying to initialize HTML elements that have been removed
- See if you are trying to call methods in JS files you are no longer including
- See if you are including the JS file that provides the functionality you need (not just for tooltips, but any components you use on the page).

  ```
  <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/bootstrap.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/animate.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
      ... your HTML code ...
      <script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
      <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="/Scripts/app/inspinia.js"></script> <!-- if using INSPINIA -->
      ... your JavaScript initializers ...
  </body>
  ```

Failure of ANY of the above items can (and often does) prevent javascript from loading and/or running, and that keeps everything nice and broken.

## WORKING EXAMPLES

Let's say you have a badge, and you want it to show a tooltip when the user hovers over it.

*Original HTML:*

```
<span class="badge badge-sm badge-plain">Admin Mode</span>
```

### Plain Bootstrap Tooltips

If you are creating tooltips for an HTML Element, and you are using Plain Bootstrap tooltips, then you will be responsible for calling the Tooltip Initializers with your own JavaScript code.

*BEFORE*

```
<span class="badge badge-sm badge-plain">Admin Mode</span>
```

*AFTER*

```
<span 
    class="badge badge-sm badge-plain" 
    data-toggle="tooltip" 
    data-placement="right" 
    title="Tooltip on right" 
 >Admin Mode</span>
```

*INITIALIZER*

```
<script>
    // Initialize any Tooltip on this page
    $(document).ready(function () 
        {
            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
        }
    );
</script>
```

### Bootstrap Template Tooltips (such as INSPINIA)

If you are using a bootstrap template (such as INSPINIA), you are including a supporting script to support the template features:

```
    <script src="/Scripts/app/inspinia.js" />
```

In the case of INSPINIA, the included script automatically initializes all tooltips by running the following javascript code when the document is finished loading:

```
// Tooltips demo
$('.tooltip-demo').tooltip({
    selector: "[data-toggle=tooltip]",
    container: "body"
});
```

Because of this, you do NOT have to initialize INSPINIA-style Tooltips yourself.  But you DO have to format your elements in a specific way.  The Initializer looks for HTML elements with `tooltip-demo` in the `class` attribute, then calls the `tooltip()` method to initialize any **child** elements that have the attribute `data-toggle="tooltip"` defined.

For our example badge, place an outer element around it (like a `<div>` or `<span>`) that has `class="tooltip-demo"`, then place the `data-toggle`, `data-placement`, and `title` attributes for the actual tooltip within the element that is the badge.  Modify the original HTML from above to look something like this:

*BEFORE*

```
<span class="badge badge-sm badge-plain">Admin Mode</span>
```

*AFTER*

```
<span class="tooltip-demo">
    <span 
        class="badge badge-sm badge-plain" 
        data-toggle="tooltip" 
        data-placement="right" 
        title="Tooltip on right" 
     >Admin Mode</span>
</span>
```

*INITIALIZER*

```
None
```

Note that any child elements within the `<span class="tooltip-demo">` element will have their tooltip properly prepared.  I could have three child elements, all needing tooltips, and place them within one container.

#### Multiple Items, each with a Tooltip

```
<span class="tooltip-demo">
    <span class="badge badge-sm badge-plain" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="A Tooltip">Text 001</span>
    <span class="badge badge-sm badge-plain" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Another Tooltip">Text 002</span>
    <span class="badge badge-sm badge-plain" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Third Tooltip">Text 003</span>
</span>
```

The best use for this would be to add the `class="tooltip-demo"` to a `<td>` or an outermost `<div>` or `<span>`.

### Plain Bootstrap Tooltips while using a Template

If you are using INSPINIA, but you don't want to add extra outer `<div>` or `<span>` tags to create tooltips, you can use standard Bootstrap Tooltips without interfering with the template.  In this case, you will be responsible for initializing the Tooltips yourself.  However, you should use a custom value in the  `class` attribute to identify your Tooltip items.  This will keep your Tooltip initializer from interfering with elements affected by INSPINIA.  In our example, let's use `standalone-tt`:

*BEFORE*

```
<span class="badge badge-sm badge-plain">Admin Mode</span>
```

*AFTER*

```
<span 
    class="standalone-tt badge badge-sm badge-plain" 
    data-toggle="tooltip" 
    data-placement="right" 
    title="Tooltip on right" 
 >Admin Mode</span>
```

*INITIALIZER*

```
<script>
    // Initialize MY standalone tooltips, ignoring INSPINIA-affected elements
    $(document).ready(function () 
        {
            $('.standalone-tt').tooltip();
        }
    );
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use **[Popper.js](https://popper.js.org/)**

```
<script src="JavaScript/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="JavaScript/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

And call tooltip function:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle=tooltip]').tooltip();
});
```

Comment: "Tooltips rely on the 3rd party library `Popper.js` for positioning. You must include `popper.min.js` before `bootstrap.js` or use `bootstrap.bundle.min.js` / `bootstrap.bundle.js` which contains `Popper.js` in order for tooltips to work!"

Answer (score 3):

I have added jquery and bootstrap-tooltip.js in header. Adding this code in footer works for me! but when i add the same code in header it doesn't work!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.some-class').tooltip({ selector: "a" });
</script>
```

Comment: In this case the DOM hasn't loaded yet so all elements my not exist on the page.  Wrap the code above in `$(function() { ... });`

Answer (score 3):

If using Rails+Haml is much easier to include the tooltip, just do:

```
= link_to '', some_path(), :class => "btn btn-success btn-mini icon-plane", :rel => "tooltip", :title => "Referential Guide"
```

That is just add the following line at the end of the element.

```
:rel => "tooltip", :title => "Referential Guide"
```

Comment: Was really hoping that was going to work for me, but alas it did not.

Comment: Now I am more into Djanto than Rails but if you paste your code I might try to give you some tip.

Answer (score 3):

In my particular case, it didn't work because I was including two versions of jQuery. One for bootstrap, but another one (another version) for Google Charts.

When I remove the jQuery loading for the charts, it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

If you are creating your html that contains the tooltip with javascript, and then inserting it into the document, you have to activate the popover/tooltip AFTER you have inserted the html into the document, not on document load...

Answer (score 3):

I just added:

```
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/assets/js/docs.min.js"></script>
```

below bootstrap.min.js and it works.

Answer (score 2):

You must put the tooltip javascript **after** the html. like this :

```
<a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="Title Here"> I am Here</a>

<script>
$("* [rel='tooltip']").tooltip({
   html: true, 
   placement: 'bottom'
});

</script>
```

Or use $(document).ready :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("* [rel='tooltip']").tooltip({
   html: true, 
   placement: 'bottom'
});

});

</script>
```

The tooltip not working because you put the **tooltip html before the javascript**, so they don't know if there is a javascript for the tooltip. In my opinion, the script is read from the top to the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and especially if you are running in a button container like a vertical button container. In that case you have to set the container as the 'body'

```
I have added a jsfiddle example
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/svader/8LvJQ/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Put your code inside document ready

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($("[rel=tooltip]").length) {
        $("[rel=tooltip]").tooltip();
    }
});
```

In my case I was also missing the tooltip css classes on http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css
so son't forget that.

Answer (score 1):

From bootstrap [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/) on tooltips

Tooltips are opt-in for performance reasons, so you must initialize them yourself.
 One way to initialize all tooltips on a page would be to select them by their data- 
 toggle attribute:

```
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following. Add the

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("[rel='tooltip']").tooltip();
    });
</script>
```

code somewhere on your page (preferably in the `<head>` section).

Also add `data-toggle: "tooltip"` to anything you want to enable with it.

Answer (score 0):

Add `data-toggle="tooltip"` at whatever elements you want with a tooltip.

Answer (score -1):

**Quick and lighter alternative to Bootstrap tooltip plugin:**

### HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class="mytooltip" id="pwdLabel">
        <label class="control-label" for="password">Password</label>

        <div class="mytooltiptext" id="pwdLabel_tttext">
            6 characters long, must include letters and numbers
        </div>                                

    </div>

    <input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password" autocomplete="off"
           class="form-control" 
           style="width:125px" />
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
<style>
    .mytooltiptext {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0px;
        top: -45px;
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
        border: 1px dashed silver;
        padding:3px;
        font-size: small;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .mytooltip {
        position: relative;
    }

    .mytooltip label {
        border-bottom: 1px dashed black !important;
    }
</style>
```

### JSCRIPT:

```
$(".mytooltip").mouseover(function(){
    var elm = this.id;
    $("#" + elm + "_tttext").fadeIn("slow");
});

var ttTmo;
$(".mytooltip").mouseout(function(){
    var elm = this.id;
    clearTimeout(ttTmo);
    ttTmo = setTimeout(function(){
        $("#" + elm + "_tttext").fadeOut("slow");
    },3000);
});
```

Label/text must be enclosed in a wrapper of class "mytooltip" This wrapper must have an Id.

After the label there is the tool tip text wrapped in a div of class "mytooltiptext" and id consisting of the id of the parent wrapper + "_tttext". Other options for selectors can be used.

Hope it helps.