# How do I bind Twitter Bootstrap tooltips to dynamically created elements?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter bootstrap tooltips with javascript like the following:

```
$('a[rel=tooltip]').tooltip();
```

My markup looks like this:

```
<a rel="tooltip" title="Not implemented" class="btn"><i class="icon-file"></i></a>
```

This works fine, but I add `<a>` elements dynamically and the tooltips aren't showing up for those dynamic elements.  I know it's because I only bind .tooltip() once when the document is finished loaded with the typical jquery `$(document).ready(function()` functionality.

How can I bind this to dynamically created elements?  Usually I would do this via the jquery live() method.  However, what is the event that I use to bind?  I'm just not sure how to hook up the bootstrap .tooltip() with jquery .live().

I've found one way to make this work is something like this:

```
/* Add new 'rows' when plus sign is clicked */
$("a.add").live('click', function () {
    var clicked_li = $(this).parent('li');
    var clone = clicked_li.clone();

    clone.find(':input').each(function() {
        $(this).val('');
    });

    clicked_li.after(clone);
    $('a[rel=tooltip]').tooltip();
});
```

This works, but seems kind of hackish.  I'm also calling the exact same .tooltip() line in the $(ready) call.  So, do the elements that exist when the page first loads and match that selector end up with the tooltip twice?

I don't see any problems with this approach.  I'm just looking for a best practice or understanding of the behavior.

Comment: hmm good question, will this help? https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/2374

Comment: That's an interesting read, but I'm only wanting a single type of tooltip.  I just want to make sure any dynamically added elements that match the tooltip selector get added, which isn't the case.

Comment: Great question. Seems like an oversite on the part of twitter.

Comment: @durden2.0 How did Christians answer work for you? Care to accept as correct?

Comment: Not really related to your question but... I find it bad style to hijack the `rel` attribute.  This is non-semantic and was originated over a decade ago as a hack.  Nowadays, every single browser going back several years supports `data-*` attributes and there's no more reason not to use them.

Answer (score 523, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$('body').tooltip({
    selector: '[rel=tooltip]'
});
```

Comment: Great. This is the correct answer, because it's basically the substitute of live/on.

Comment: @CalvinL [If a selector is provided, tooltip objects will be delegated to the specified targets.](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips)

Comment: This is also the solution for elements added after page load by an ajax call.

Comment: What I don't like about this solution is that you can't have multiple configuration of tooltips. For example, it doesn't work if you have tooltips that are placed on top and others that are placed on bottom.

Comment: @barbolo, simply use different selectors for different configurations. This is the right solution. Btw, it works also with Popover.

Comment: @EnricoCarlesso how do you use different selectors for different configurations? I tried: $("body .mySelector").popover({..}) but that didn't work. and also multiple $("body").popover({selector:".mySelector1"}); $("body").popover({selector:".mySelector2"}); neither worked

Comment: This works well, but in my Google Maps (jquery-ui-map) application, using 'body' as the selector was causing "something squirrelly" to happen within the map. I used an internal div instead, e.g. `$('#map')`, and my problem seemed fixed. This might also help readers who have the same question as @BZ.

Comment: @EnricoCarlesso, I am also trying to get different configurations working, but they do not. Performing the `$("body").tooltip()` call more than once seems to overwrite the previous one, even if the selector is different.

Comment: Well, this answer is quite old, @JohnDubya, not sure if anything has changed and which bootstrap you are using. Anyway, I whould say that you should delegate the configuration to the data-whatever field in the html field. Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/carlesso/4Qjcr/

Comment: Oh my gosh, how simple. It's always the simple method you forget about. Sigh. Thank you, Enrico, the data-placement attribute should do nicely, instead of setting multiple configurations. SMH

Comment: As of JQuery 1.10, "selector:" changed to "items:". http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Comment: bootstrap 3 use $('body').tooltip({selector:'[data-toggle=tooltip]'});

Comment: console error TypeError: c is undefined.but working fine

Comment: Anyone know if there is a performance hit using this technique?

Answer (score 158):

If you have multiple tooltip configurations that you want to initialise, this works well for me.

```
$("body").tooltip({
    selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip"]'
});
```

You can then set the property on individual elements using `data` attributes.

Comment: Great tip. I had to change it to $("body").tooltip({ selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip"]' });

Comment: great! for use inside a table add  container: 'body'  to avoid extra width.

Comment: This works really well. I tried a whole bunch of stuff on a dynamic table but nothing really worked until this.

Comment: Works with Bootstrap 4 as well!

Answer (score 17):

For me, only catching the mouseenter event was a bit buggy, and the tooltip was not showing/hiding properly. 
I had to write this, and it is now working perfectly:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter','[rel=tooltip]', function(){
    $(this).tooltip('show');
});

$(document).on('mouseleave','[rel=tooltip]', function(){
    $(this).tooltip('hide');
});
```

Comment: This was very helpful insite as to why .on('hover') wouldn't work right.

Comment: This was all I needed to use for my implementation of using handlebars.js. If I wasn't using handlebars.js, the accepted answer also worked.

Comment: This is how I used to do this but you lose a lot of options like hover delays that you would need to implement manually with this I think.

Answer (score 15):

I've posted longer answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20877657/207661

TL;DR: You need only one line of code that runs in document ready event:

```
$(document.body).tooltip({ selector: "[title]" });
```

Other more complicated code suggested in other answers don't seem necessary (I've tested this with Bootstrap 3.0).

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: This worked for my case. I used a table with Tablesorter 2.26.2 and populated values via Ajax call. Problem was that the html tooltip was shown as HTML text instead of rendered output.
This is the only solution worked for me in the first go. +1 and lot of thanks!

Answer (score 8):

For me, this js reproduces the same problem that happens with [Paola](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1436314/paola)

My solution:

```
$(document.body).tooltip({selector: '[title]'})
.on('click mouseenter mouseleave','[title]', function(ev) {
    $(this).tooltip('mouseenter' === ev.type? 'show': 'hide');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than search it in full Body.
One could just use dynamic title option already available in such scenarios I think:

```
$btn.tooltip({
  title: function(){
    return $(this).attr('title');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a combination of these answers gave me the best outcome - allowing me to still position the tooltip and attach it to the relevant container:

```
$('body').on('mouseenter', '[rel=tooltip]', function(){
  var el = $(this);
  if (el.data('tooltip') === undefined) {
    el.tooltip({
      placement: el.data("placement") || "top",
      container: el.data("container") || false
    });
  }
  el.tooltip('show');
});

$('body').on('mouseleave', '[rel=tooltip]', function(){
  $(this).tooltip('hide');
});
```

Relevant HTML:

```
<button rel="tooltip" class="btn" data-placement="bottom" data-container=".some-parent" title="Show Tooltip">
    <i class="icon-some-icon"></i>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Bootstrap 5, which doesn't use jQuery, you can do this:

```js
const btn = document.createElement('button');
btn.innerHTML = 'Click me';
btn.dataset['toggle'] = 'tooltip';
btn.dataset['placement'] = 'top';
btn.title = 'Your Tooltip Here';
new bootstrap.Tooltip(btn);

document.getElementById('parent').appendChild(btn);
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-CuOF+2SnTUfTwSZjCXf01h7uYhfOBuxIhGKPbfEJ3+FqH/s6cIFN9bGr1HmAg4fQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-popRpmFF9JQgExhfw5tZT4I9/CI5e2QcuUZPOVXb1m7qUmeR2b50u+YFEYe1wgzy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="parent"></div>
```