# Bootstrap tooltip usage

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I am adding bootstrap tooltip to my a tag like this :

```
jQuery('span.arUp a').attr("data-placement", "top");
jQuery('span.arUp a').attr("data-toggle", "tooltip");
jQuery('span.arUp a').attr("data-original-title", "Tooltip on top");
```

and a tag looks like this :

```
<a rel="next" href="http://roadmap.private.net/?p=28" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Tooltip on top">Fedrer</a>
```

But no tooltip is coming. Please help!!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446318/bootstrap-tooltips-not-working

Comment: @Skelly It doesn't appear to be a duplicate. Sankalp, is the above HTML the output _after_ the jQuery has run, or is the HTML delivered to the browser as you have written it?

Answer (score 3):

[Bootstrap tooltip](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips) usage:

```
<a rel="next" href="http://roadmap.private.net/?p=28" title="Tooltip on top">Fedrer</a>

$(function(){
    $('span.arUp a').tooltip({
        placement: 'top'
    });
});
```

and make sure you include the bootstrap js file.

Comment: i have included bootstrap file but i am not getting any tooltip

Comment: check the usage. That is now how you invoke the tooltips

Comment: I have included bootstrapmin.js and  jQuery('span.arUp a').tooltip({
    placement: 'top',
    title: 'Test'
}); . But error is tooltip is not a function

Comment: it is bootstrap.min.js. - Check for console log errors if any.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the `data-*`, you are using the `auto` mode of the tooltip, which it automatically adds itself to the elements it finds.

Since you are adding the `data-*` with JS instead of directly into the HTML, you need:

- Add the `.js` file AFTER your additions

or

- Call `$('span.arUp a').tooltip` after your code.

Comment: I have included bootstrapmin.js and  jQuery('span.arUp a').tooltip({
    placement: 'top',
    title: 'Test'
}); . But error is tooltip is not a function

Comment: @SankalpMishra `is not a function` means it does not loaded or does not exist. Open your bootstrapmin and do a quick Ctrl+F looking for "tooltip". Sometimes you got a build without it. And don't forget to put your code inside a `$(document).ready(function(){ /*yourstuff*/ });`

Answer (score 1):

If you need the `tooltip` feature to work with dynamic elements, you can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").tooltip({
        selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip"]'
    });
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/FHjVs/1/

Then, whenever an element has an attribute `data-toggle="tooltip"`, a tooltip will be applied, without having to run JavaScript/jQuery code.

Reference:

- [How do I bind Twitter Bootstrap tooltips to dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958825/how-do-i-bind-twitter-bootstrap-tooltips-to-dynamically-created-elements)