# Loaded() content won't inherit javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I.e, I have two files:

- index.php
- some-content.php

In the index.php is where I load my CSS and JS:

```
<head><link href="css/web.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /></head>
<body><script src="js/web.js" type="text/javascript"></script></body>
```

Now, what I am doing is loading "some-content.php" with a load() event in "js/web.js":

```
 $("#content").load('some-content.php');
```

Long story short:

When I load "some-content.php" it inherits all the necessary CSS styles from css/web.css without me having to include another link href in "some-content.php"

But none of the JS scripts seem te be working - the ones stored in js/web.js that is srced in index.php

Am I force to add:

```
<script src="js/web.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

again in "some-content.php"?

Thanks

Comment: It depends on the javascript, if you are binding for example events using `on()` it could work. You need to post the javascript.

Comment: use the complete callback of the load method to reinitialize tooltip() plugin on new added elements. If it's the tooltip plugin of twitter bootstrap you are using, this plugin already have its own method to delegate it, using option select or something like that, check relevant DOC. **UPDATE** for twitter tooltip, it's selector option: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10420203/1414562

Comment: I tried adding: "$(document).tooltip({ selector:'[rel="tooltip"]' });" and it works fine, only it is ignoring the data-trigger field... (takes on hover as default)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usually happens because you are binding your events with direct bindings such as...

```
$('.myClass').click(function () {
    //...
});
```

This will only apply to `.myClass` elements that are present at the time this binding runs.

If you want to apply to elements that will be added to the DOM later, use the more dynamic `on` binding.

```
$(document).on('click', '.myClass', function () {
    //...
});
```

You can also be more specific - rather than using `document` - but that was for the purposes of the example.

Comment: +1 bcoz this was the one which helped me a lot at my works :)

Comment: this accepted answer doesn't seem to answer OP's issue, did i miss something??? Correct answer is jeroen's one

Comment: @A.Wolff Hey, that's exactly what was going on. I had to add the on() function to all my events :)

Comment: @James i was thinking you were looking for the tooltip plugin but you edited your question making it no more relevant. Delegation with .on() is for events, not plugins

Comment: Well Steve seemed to realize what my problem might of been. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3):

You are binding the tooltip to the elements on page load. When you add new content, you need to bind the tooltip to the newly added elements. You can do that in the callback function of you ajax call, for example like:

```
$("#content").load('some-content.php', function() {
  $(this).find("[rel='tooltip']").tooltip();
  // or put stuff like that in an initialization function and call that instead...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`.load()`  is a AJAX method that loads dynamic contents.

Use `on()` for dynamic generated contents

```
$('selector').on('event',function(){
//something
});
```

Example:

```
$( "#data" ).on( "click", function() {
alert( $( this ).text() );
});
```

Read more about [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)