# Jquery plugin how to implement .live or .on so it works with new elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an `HTML` page that uses `jQuery` and also have an external plugin `tooltipster`.

In order to intialize the plugin I have to do this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tooltip').tooltipster();
});
```

The HTML is very simple you just have to set the `class` to `"tootlip"`:

```
'<span class="tooltip" title="This is my spans tooltip message!">Some other text</span>'
```

This works great for static elements in the `DOM`.

[image]

The problem comes for new elements added after the DOM is created.
This is similar to `jQuery` when using `.on()` or `.live()` for elements created after.

So If I have:

```
 $('#newelement').click(function(e) {

                    $('#elements').html('<span class="tooltip" title="This is my spans tooltip message!">New element</span>');

                });
```

> Any clue on how to make this work? Can I use `.on()` in a way that it works for static and dynamic elements?

Comment: Have you read http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/#delegation ? might answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, for newly created elements you're better of using:

```
$(document).on("click", "#newelement", function(e) {

                $('#elements').html('<span class="tooltip" title="This is my spans tooltip message!">New element</span>');

            });
```

Comment: That's not the question. Its about having the tooltip working when new elements are added.

Comment: Ahh okay, in that case look at http://jsfiddle.net/carlesso/4Qjcr/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958825/how-do-i-bind-twitter-bootstrap-tooltips-to-dynamically-created-elements

This works with Bootstrap tooltips, and I'm assuming it should work with tooltipster as well, although I'm not familiar with the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Best solutions will be to rebind all (or if you're ambitious - only new created) tooltip element right after you create them. For example right after ajax complete you should refresh all tooltips.

Answer (score 0):

Create new function and call that function in the .on event

```
//Here call the .on to    
$("#anotherElement").on('click', function(){
     $('.tooltip').tooltipster();
     newFunction();
});

//Call the function to show title
function newFunction(){
     $('#newelement'). click(function(e){
           $('#elements').h tml('<span class="tooltip" title="This is my spans tooltip message!">New element</span>');
     });
}
```