# Appending html to a div using Jquery - add Bootstrap Tooltip to appended items

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I have an div: $(".results"). As things are happening, results get added to this div. One of the many things is a dice roll, formatted in a `<kdb>`

For Example:

```
function resultBox(result, color="red"){ return "<kbd class='"+color+"'>"+result+"</kbd>";
```

The default kdb color is red, but I've added so many colors (different colors for different result types). I want to add a tooltip to each kdb to explain the colors.

For Example:

```
function resultBox(result, color="red"){
  return "<kbd class='"+color+"' data-toggle='tooltip' title='"+colorInfo(color)+"'>"+result+"</kbd>";
}

function colorInfo(color) {
  return "blah blah";
}
```

(I **do not** need assistance with the colorInfo() function) I'm just having trouble figuring out why the Bootstrap Tooltip isn't showing properly. (Meaning: I'm seeing a standard tooltip, as if I hadn't added Bootstrap. Instead of seeing the Bootstrap default black tooltip with the little arrow)

**BEFORE YOU ANSWER PLEASE NOTE**

- Bootstrap Tooltips are formatted properly. This has been added to my main javascript page. `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();` I can use Bootstrap Tooltips normally by writting them out in normal HTML.

I'm just not sure how to bind them when dynamically creating them in Javascript

EDIT: This is not a duplicate. The question has been answered. The answer was not found in the "possible duplicate"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I bind Twitter Bootstrap tooltips to dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958825/how-do-i-bind-twitter-bootstrap-tooltips-to-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run `$(#AddedItems).tooltip()` function once you append something in DIV.

**Note:** this is not working becuase this function `($('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip())` only works on dom elements which are available in dom.