# Twitter Bootstrap tooltip for span tag (not for a tag)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

My question is based on SO question [Bootstrap tooltips not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446318/bootstrap-tooltips-not-working?rq=1)

So, the solution is to use:
jQuery:

```
$("[rel='tooltip']").tooltip();
```

html:

```
<a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="A nice tooltip">test</a>
```

And that works perfect.
My question is: what if I want to use a `<span>` tag instead of `<a>`.

Should it be `<span rel="tooltip" title="A nice tooltip">Hover on me</span>` ?

It works perfectly but I see the `rel` attribute is used for a tags.

So, what's the correct solution?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your can write in the following ways :

**Method 1**

```
  <a title="" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" href="#" data-original-title="Tooltip on top">Tooltip on top</a>
```

And Than initialize it with the following code :

```
$('a').tooltip();
```

The other way is to use classes or ids and initialize them one by one like :

**Method 2**

```
 <span class="top" title="A nice tooltip" data-original-title="Tooltip on right">Hover on me</span>      

<a class="top" title=""  href="#" data-original-title="Tooltip on top">Tooltip on top</a>
```

Than initializing it with the following code :

```
$(".top").tooltip({
placement: "top"
});
```

Jsfiddle [Method 1](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/vSTLU/2/)

Jsfiddle [Method 2](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/MxmbK/2/)

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use a `rel` attribute on a `<span>`, simply use something else like a class and update the tooltip selector, eg:

```
$("[rel='tooltip'], .tooltip").tooltip();

<span class="tooltip" title="A nice tooltip">Hover on me</span>
```

You can use any CSS selector inside the jQuery function `$()` to select any element on the page in any way.