# Bootstrap tooltip on mouse hover popover effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap tool-tip. And the normal tool-tip is shown on mouse over on the object of tool-tip but i want tool-tip popover like that is shown bootstrap documentation and i using all of .js and .css file but that is not comming proper way of requirement. And am using these some files:-

```
<script language="javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $("[rel='tooltip']").tooltip();
    })
</script>
```

And Html with img that hover tool-tip is open:-

```
<a href="#" rel='tooltip' data-placement='bottom' title="App_above_and_beyond">
    <img src="img/app_above_and_beyond.jpg" alt="App_above_and_beyond" />
</a>
```

And also using bootstrap-tooltip.js file

```
<script type="javascript" src="js/bootstrap-tooltip.js" ></script>
```

Comment: Have you seen this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/18027268/1156668

Comment: yes but tooltip popup is not enabled after using that

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Basic tooltips work fine in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ringstaff/ufKMg/17/) using your method above. What do you need it to do?

Answer (score 0):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Palapas/52VtD/688/)

make sure you have this JS file

```
http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js
```

Comment: But i am using here a plugin list slider [http://als.musings.it/] that is stop working tool-tip function.