# If tooltip have long text arrow goes down (bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I have default bootstrap tooltip with custom styles for arrows that have only font color and size, nothing special with paddings or margin.

If I have short text - it's ok:
[image: short text]

If it's a littile longer - arrow goes down through the tooltip:
[image: longer one]

another common problem - if tooltip position is near the end of the page/window:
[image]

There are the same styles for each tooltip.

I've tried to fix it by different ways based on answers from stackoverflow, but it wasn't helpful.
Please, help me to understand this strange behaviour. What style should I use for arrows to make it fixed at the border of tooltip?

PS: another detail - if I will swap "hide people" and "show feedback" tooltips - it becomes ok. So, probably it depends on tooltip position too.

Comment: try to give it a higher width it should work

Comment: @Youness if you meant arrow - it is not. If we are talking about tooltips - yes, it will fix my problem arrows, but it will crash another ones.
And making individual class for each tooltip it's not a good behaviour :)

Comment: can you show the arrow css?

Comment: @punithasubramaniv sure. As I said, nothing special: http://pastie.org/private/n4ml8j5cl85wktwujdxiuw

Comment: How can I run? And, then I want tooltip before after code like I posted for u an example

Comment: @Youness but to use max-width exactly for main .tooltip class is really helpful! Thanks! Problem that remains is tooltip at the corner, it centered his arrow incorrect.

Comment: @Youness your hint was helpful. Add please it to answer and I will approve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@Youness](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2716477/youness),

**max-width** exactly for main *.tooltip* class is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This what I expected!

Can you try it? and post your after/before pseudo code

reference

http://cssdeck.com/labs/pure-css-tooltip-with-arrow

```
    .tooltip:hover:before {
        background: #111;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
        border-radius: .5em;
        bottom: 1.35em;
        color: #fff;
        content: attr(title);
        display: block;
        left: 1em;
        padding: .3em 1em;
        position: absolute;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
        white-space: nowrap;
        z-index: 98;
    }

    .tooltip:hover:after {
        border: solid;
        border-color: #111 transparent;
        border-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8) transparent;
        border-width: .4em .4em 0 .4em;
        bottom: 1em;
        content: "";
        display: block;
        left: 2em;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 99;
    }
```

Comment: just use default bootstrap tooltip, like this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446318/bootstrap-tooltips-not-working