# Font awesome not working with tooltip

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I would like a tooltip pop up from bootstrap 4 to display when the font awesome icon is clicked. Button nothing is occurring. My code is as follows:

```
  <a href='#' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Some tooltip text!'><i class='fa fa-info-circle' aria-hidden='true'>&nbsp;</i></a>
```

would I need to make a javascript function?

EDIT:

I have the following scripts:

```
    <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"   integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/0a5d051ab0.js"></script>
```

Comment: Did you load Bootstrap's JavaScript file?

Comment: yes it is right before the closing body tag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap tooltips not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446318/bootstrap-tooltips-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

`Tooltip` is an "opt-in" component so you have to call `.tooltip()` on the elements that you want to have tooltips.

```js
$("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"   integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/0a5d051ab0.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<br><br>

<a href='#' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Some tooltip text!'><i class='fa fa-info-circle' aria-hidden='true'>&nbsp;</i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: for some reason it works here but when I add it to my code it won't work

Comment: no I checked in the console but nothing I am just going to rewrite another page and test it further. I do see I am using a different version of bootstrap but even by putting the latest one no effect.