# Bootstrap tooltip is not working on my web project

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I'm actually in a very weird situation and somehow can't be able to figure out what non-sense is happening to me. The situation is I'm actually implementing my bootstrap tooltip fine and I have checked it on the `JsFiddle`, it is working fine there too, however, after a lot of efforts, it is not getting implemented on the web project, I don't know why.

This is literally very weird. Here is my implementation which is working fine on JsFiddle.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- jQuery Script -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function (){
        $("[data-toggle=tooltip]").tooltip()
      })
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <section class="testimonial home-page" id="home">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Bringing ease to<br>each home</h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Tooltip on bottom">
Tooltip on bottom
</button>
        <div class="d-none d-sm-block" style="margin-top: 400px"></div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
```

And for the solutions I have done a lot of things but, unfortunately, all of them didn't work.

1. To take the class name into consideration

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function (){
      $(".btn-secondary").tooltip()
     })
   </script>
   ```
2. To use the body element to target the data-toggle :

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function (){
       $("body").tooltip({
         selector : '[data-toggle=tooltip]'
       })
     })
   </script>
   ```
3. To use the container as body and focus on the section :

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function (){
       $(".testimonial.home-page").tooltip({
         selector : '[data-toggle=tooltip]',
         container : 'body'
       })
     })
   </script>
   ```

This is what I'm getting on my web project:

[image: Final Result on the Web Project]

Don't take me wrong, I'm really confused about why it ain't happening since everything is fine. Any ideas would be appreciated, I'm a noob and I know that you guys can help me on this.

**EDITS**

I have checked the console and got this error saying the **.tooltip is not a function**:

[image: Error on the console]

Comment: Don't load jQuery twice!

Comment: I ran your code and the tooltip appeared. I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Quentin, that is why I'm finding a problem in that. It is very weird and hence taking my all efforts, still not getting resolved. I have commented the second jquery loading from my project but still not working

Comment: it seems that something isn't imlemented.  I recommend proof all your steps, (*Edit: sorry didn't see the script tag).  Which brwoser your running? (Version). Or could you maybe send an url to look at?

Comment: @Quentin I have the error in my console, kindly take a look t that

Comment: @Rakowu, please see my edits. Thanks. hope you will get the idea, weird that the tooltip function is not getting recognized.

Comment: why do you use 2 jquery?

Comment: Why you use  cross origin?

Comment: Removed the loading of jquery twice, still facing the same issue @Vitalii

Comment: What does that mean @Rakowu, using cross origin?

Comment: in your script you have: crossorigin="anonymous", is it a iframe what your are trying to run? *Edit: ok sorry i see, bootstrap implemented his cdn in this way. sorry my bad for not reading well.

Comment: Try to debug a bit. Push  console.log($(document).tooltip) inside your init script

Comment: I guess the question is a bit silly but, Is the closing html tag missing?

Comment: No, it is not missing, otherwise my whole project would not have been running. @Rakowu Could you please look at my edits, because the problem is there only since the jquery is not able to identify the **tooltip()**

Comment: @Vitalii It is coming `undefined` in the console with the error which I just mentioned in the EDITS.  Tooltip function is not getting recognized by the jquery

Comment: @AlokKumarVerma And one more thing. After a while, try to do the same check with console directly from console manually. Not from code.

Comment: I run your code on my webspace and everything work fine. What webserwer do you use? Maybe there are some restrictions? What happens when you run jquery and bootsrap on your server instead of cdn ?

Answer (score 4):

Try to call the Tooltip function in this way and pass the options as HTML attributes. You can check out some working examples [here](http://www.bootstrapdash.com/demo/star-admin-pro/jquery/pages/ui-features/tooltips.html).

```
<button class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Basic tooltip">Hover me</button>

<script>
 $(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add few attributes inside `tooltip` function `{container:'body', trigger: 'hover', placement:"bottom"}`

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(
        {container:'body', trigger: 'hover', placement:"bottom"}
        );   
    });
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- jQuery Script -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    
  </head>
  <body>
     <section class="testimonial home-page" id="home">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Bringing ease to<br>each home</h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Tooltip on bottom">
Tooltip on bottom
</button>
        <div class="d-none d-sm-block" style="margin-top: 400px"></div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
```

Comment: As far as I understand he can't call .tooltip cause it is undefined.

Comment: I agree with you, same thing is happening @Vitalii

Comment: @Vitalii and alok for .tooltip undefined there is two case ... first bootstarp js not called properly or you need to add title in element when you use tooltip.. same case also listed on github  https://github.com/almasaeed2010/AdminLTE/issues/1128

Answer (score 1):

Solution is this, there was an error in calling of some jQuery files which was not called properly and hence whole project was messing up. So if you are using the `popups`, `tooltips` then make sure you call the jquery in a correct format. Here is the answer and how I got it working, just look at the calling of jQuery files and the other files accordingly and then in body I have called the script for the tooltip :

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <!-- SLICK SLIDER-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/slick/slick.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/slick/slick-theme.css"/>

    <!-- MATERIAL ICONS-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- jQuery first, then jQuery min.js, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="testimonial home-page" id="home">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Bringing ease to<br>each home</h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Tooltip on bottom">
Tooltip on bottom
</button>
        <div class="d-none d-sm-block" style="margin-top: 400px"></div>
      </div>
    </section>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function (){
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
          container : 'body'
        })
      })
    </script>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

HTML

```html
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Title Here">Hyperlink Text</a>
```

jQUERY

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").tooltip({ selector: '[data-toggle=tooltip]' });
});
```

get it from other thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/22569369/11934267

Answer (score 0):

My issue was the tooltips css conflicting .tooltip-inner and .tooltip coming from the _tooltip.scss files this was setting an opacity:0;

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap V5 or higher you have to enable the tooltip manually.

```
var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
})
```

For more info check out this [Enable Tooltip](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/tooltips/#example-enable-tooltips-everywhere)

Answer (score -2):

you can use **[Popper.js](https://popper.js.org/)**

```
<script src="JavaScript/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="JavaScript/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

And call tooltip function:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle=tooltip]').tooltip();
});
```