# Bootstrap popover not working with no error

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am creating a website using bootstrap 5, I would like to have a button that when the user clicks it that a popover appears.

I have added jQuery and the popper.js files to my files. However when I click on the button nothing happens. I have checked the console and it doesn't seem to show any errors. I have no idea what is wrong.

Here is my button code.

```html
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Vivamus
sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus."><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart" style="color: #fff;">
  Cart </i>
</button>
```

Here is my jQuery code

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();   
  });
```

Here are the jQuery and popper.js files I have linked.

```js
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
```

I am wonder if I have linked the wrong version of the files as the bootstrap website wasn't very helpful when it came to this.

Comment: Load jquery before bootstrap

Comment: doesn't fix the problem

Comment: Try with `$(document).ready(function() {` Arrow functions sometimes makes a problem

Comment: tried that as well and still having the same problem.

Comment: Are you sure there is no warnings or errors in the console?

Comment: yes, I have checked on a number of browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `data-*` **attributes** with `data-bs-*` (For example: `data-toggle` to `data-bs-toggle` and so on) and change the script to the one provided below to turn on popovers.

In addition, make sure you include [Bootstrap assets](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/) correctly and everything should be fine. In your case you have not included bootstrap css file so the popover would show up with **no styling**. Again you can check the below snippet for more details.

```html
<html>

<head>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-container="body" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-placement="bottom" data-bs-content="Vivamus
sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus."><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart" style="color: #fff;">
  Cart </i>
</button>





<script>

var popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]'))
var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function (popoverTriggerEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl)
})

</script>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: the bootstrap css is linked at the start of the file, I just didn't show it here

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is too late...but try use the following...

`<p>This<a href="#" data-toggle="popover" role="button" class="btn btn-secondary popover-test" title="Popover title" data-bs-content="Popover body content is set in this attribute."><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart" style="color: #fff;"></i></a> triggers a popover on click.</p>`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").popover({ selector: '[data-toggle="popover"]' });
});
```

Useful answer here...
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22569369/6790839